# Can we change Redirect_uri in Azure Ad

Tags: spring-boot, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am new to azure ad. I am following the documentation provided by Microsoft.
Here is the link for that

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-active-directory#summary

In this, the redirect Uri is mentioned as http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/azure.
But when I change it to http://localhost:8080/index

It gives me this message **"Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in.
AADSTS50011: The reply url specified in the request does not match the reply urls configured for the application: '0a911c88-3038-487d-9a97-3754a1c42017'."**

Comment: Did you set the `spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azure.redirect-uri-template` in the [application.properties](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-spring-boot/tree/master/azure-spring-boot-samples/azure-active-directory-spring-boot-backend-sample#want-to-take-full-control-over-every-configuration-property) file?

Comment: I hadn't set it. After that a new issue came. There is a mapping in my controller class

"/index". I have set the redirect uri as "http://localhost:8080/index". So in my browser.. After successfully authenticating the user.. i am redirected to this page.
The page doesn't work.. But I can see the code in the url.

How can I get that code?  Could you help me

Comment: I'm afraid you may need to accept it as answer and ask a new question, because it is a new issue. Include the details about `The page doesn't work` in the new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the issue, you need to set `spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azure.redirect-uri-template` in the [`application.properties`](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-spring-boot/tree/master/azure-spring-boot-samples/azure-active-directory-spring-boot-backend-sample#want-to-take-full-control-over-every-configuration-property) file.